# jquerymobile rendering incorrectly in android webview

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-webview

I am using jquery mobile 1.3.1 inside an android WebView, to render a form interface. On the android browser it renders quite ok, but it is obviously wrong when presented within the WebView, as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOr8Q.png). I've seen this happen in 2.3 and 4.2 devices, and can remember not having this issue with a previous version of jquery mobile (sadly, do not exactly remember which one anymore).

Does anyone have an idea on how to go about correcting this into something more acceptable?

Comment: Tell me are you using local js/css jQiery Mobile files of remote files from jQuery CDN?

Comment: Gajotres, I am using local ones

Comment: You pointed in the right direction Gajotres, evidently I had a stale version of the images I was using.

Comment: I am glad you have found the problem :)